# Java BufferedImage throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, image, file, bufferedimage

I am making a space shooter in Java, but when I try to load up the image resources, I get a null pointer exception. Everything works fine except the images. Am I coding the directory wrong? How can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
BufferedReader highScoreReader;
BufferedWriter highScoreWriter;

try {
    playerImage = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("src/res/player.png"));
    bulletImage = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("src/res/bullet.png"));
    enemyImage = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("src/res/enemy.png"));

    highScoreReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/files/HIGH_SCORE.txt"));
    highScoreWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/files/HIGH_SCORE.txt"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my file directories:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen it done that way.

Try this

```
try {
    playerImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("src/res/player.png"));
catch(IOException e) {
}
```

or

```
try {
    playerImage = ImageIO.read(new File("src/res/player.png"));
catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work
Are there any other problems?

Comment: Can you tell us what the error is? You never specified what the problem is. What are you doing with the images?

Comment: I am drawing them to a frame. When I am running the code, the images are throwing me a NPE. Everything but the images work correctly.

Comment: try removing "src" from your path to the images. Your `FileReader` manages to find it's files without it. And use the second method. Don't worry about getting it as a stream, just use `ImageIO.read(new File(filepath))`

Comment: I am still getting the error. Maybe its a glitch in eclipse.

Comment: Unlikely to be a glitch, mate

Comment: I did some more testing with your method and it is outputting an IOException. It says it cannot read the file.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably, you need to copy your images into the build directory of your project.  If you want them treated as classpath resources, which it seems you do, make sure they're in a source folder in eclipse (or, if you use maven or similar, in the `src/main/resources` folder.  The point is, they need to be copied to the place where the `.class` file lives when it's running.

Remember: `class.getResourceAsStream(...)` returns things from the `classpath` not from your source path.

Answer (score 0):

Arnav Garg has discovered the problem.

When your code says something like:
`file("src/res/player.png")`
the file is not there, i.e.
`file.exists()`
will return false

Find out where java thinks the file is.

try using
`file.getAbsolutePath()`
and compare that to your directory structure.